# Return one of each value Parse.com Query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a class `Event`. Each `Event` has an `EventParent`, and an `EventName`.

What I am looking to do is write a query that returns each unique `EventParent` once.

`EventParent| EventName`

`NY Sports  |  MSG`

`NY Sports  | Barclays`

`CA Sports  | Staples Center`

`CA Sports  | Oracle Arena`

In the above example, I'd like to get `NY Sports` and `CA Sports` as my result. What is the best way to do this using a Parse query?

Comment: Are you querying against EventParent directly or are you retrieving a set of Events and then wanting to look at their parents?

Comment: I am querying the Event class for the key `EventParent`... reason being I want to populate a TableView with the results, whereby a user can click on one of those cells and segue to a TableView with the values from `EventName `

Comment: There is no point in querying Parse for information you already have. I would loop through the events and add each event parent name to a set.  Use the values from the set to populate the tableview.